# How to support comma separated list queryParam in RestEasy

Tags: java, list, resteasy, query-string

When using a list as a QueryParam in RestEasy, (@QueryParam List strings),
following url works fine -
?strings=123&strings=456
this works and you get list with 2 values.

but when you pass the value as follows -
?strings=123,456
it gives "123,456" as a single value which is not expected behaviour.

How to get strings=123,456 as a List of 123 and 456.

One option is to create Provider class for Set and modify the fromString and toString method, after this strings=123,456 start working and it gives list with two elements and 123 and 456, but strings=123&strings=456 dont work now and it gives list with only one element 123.

Let me know how can i get both the behaviour in RestEasy QueryParam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by implementing ContainerRequestFilter and in the filter method updated the actual URL and set it back into requestContext. 
e.g. original URl -
http://localhost:8080/api?tags=123,456

updated Url -
http://localhost:8080/api?tags=123&tags=456